# MS Project VSTO

Tags: vsto, ms-project

I am using Project 2016 to integrate with an ERP. My goal is to read Project's Resource Information.

To do that I save the database in an mdb file.

The line that do this trick is:

```
projApp.VisualReportsSaveDatabase(FileNameCompleteMdb, PjVisualReportsDataLevel.pjLevelDays)
```

Everything works fine, but some of my users, they are using Project with Portuguese Language. When the Access mdb file is created, many table fields have their names in Portuguese which causes all my SQL Statements to fail.

My question is:

Is there any way to force Project to export always the mdb file in English.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

After a little research I got to this solution. It isn't the best solution, but works.

First Step, declare all fields as strings

Dim _Code As String
        Dim _Name As String
        Dim _Start As String
        Dim _Finish As String
        Dim _Work As String
        Dim _ActualWork As String

Second step:

Set your strings with the FieldName read from your project application. At this point , project will return its FieldNames according to the language that it is set.

```
    _Code = projApp.FieldConstantToFieldName(PjField.pjResourceCode)
    _Name = projApp.FieldConstantToFieldName(PjField.pjResourceName)
    _Start = projApp.FieldConstantToFieldName(PjField.pjResourceStart)
    _Finish = projApp.FieldConstantToFieldName(PjField.pjResourceFinish)
    _Work = projApp.FieldConstantToFieldName(PjField.pjResourceWork)
    _ActualWork = projApp.FieldConstantToFieldName(PjField.pjResourceActualWork)


    Dim qryResource As String = "Select [ResourceUID], [Code], [Name], [Start], [Finish], [Work], [Actual Work] From MSP_EpmResource Where [Code] >'0';"
```

Step 3:
With your sql statement in English, simply replace the original FieldNames with your variables:

```
    qryResource = qryResource.Replace("Code", _Code)
    qryResource = qryResource.Replace("Name", _Name)
    qryResource = qryResource.Replace("Start", _Start)
    qryResource = qryResource.Replace("Finish", _Finish)
    qryResource = qryResource.Replace("Actual Work", _ActualWork)
    qryResource = qryResource.Replace("Work", _Work)
```

Finally , you gonna have a valid sql statement, depending on your application language.

tks